Evaluate $\int\frac{x+||x|+3|x-2|+|2+|x+5|||}{||x|+|x+2|x-5|||}dx$?
Evaluate $$\int\frac{x+||x|+3|x-2|+|2+|x+5|||}{||x|-6+|x+2|x-5|||}dx$$ ?
Here this integral is in indefinite form and $|x|$ means the absolute value of $x$.
I am unable to Approach a single line for this integral. I am extremely sorry for that.
But still let me discuss some of my thoughts.
Generally while solving modulus questions in case of indefinite integrals then we take some cases/conditions and then solve it.
So, I am also thinking by the same way.
So, I took into consideration some cases like : $$|x|>0 ; |x|<0 ; |x-2|>0 ; |x-2|<0 ; |x+5|>0 ; |x+5|<0 |x-5|>0 ; |x-5|<0$$
Now as far as I guessed I have to take their intersection point.
Now, if I take into consideration the cases like
$|x-5|>0 , |x-2|>0 , |x|>0 , |x+5|>0$
Now if we carefully observe then the intersection point is $[5,\infty)$
Similarly for the cases
$|x-5|<0 , |x-2|<0 , |x|<0 , |x+5|<0$
Now if we carefully observe then the intersection point is $[-5,\infty)$
But I am having one confusion in my mind.
The confusion is that can this integral be solved only with these conditions ?
I really can't understand anything.
Please  help me.

For legibility with triple-nested absolute value operators, it may be helpful to use function call notation instead of vertical bars, i.e.,
$$f(x) = \frac{x+\operatorname{abs}(\operatorname{abs}(x)+3*\operatorname{abs}(x-2)+\operatorname{abs}(2+\operatorname{abs}(x+5)))}{\operatorname{abs}(\operatorname{abs}(x)-6+2*\operatorname{abs}(x-5))}$$

I'm confused at the large number of upvotes (5, and I'm the 20th view), and the quick downvote on the answer. There is something atypical happening here.

$$I = \int f(x) dx$$
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2 + \frac{5}{2(x-2)}, & x\lt -5\\
1+ \frac{9}{4-2x}, & -5 \le x \lt 0\\
\frac{13}{4}, & 0 \le x \lt 2\\
\frac{1+6x}{4}, & 2 \le x \lt 5\\
\frac{1+6x}{4(x-4)}, & x \ge 5\\
\end{cases}
$$
Now you can integrate piece wise.

The command of Mathematica 14.1
Integrate[(x +  RealAbs[RealAbs[x] + 3*RealAbs[x - 2] + 
RealAbs[2 + RealAbs[x + 5]]])/ RealAbs[RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[x + 2*RealAbs[x - 5]]], x]

answers
$$ \begin{cases}
 2 x+\frac{17}{2} \log (10-2 x) & x\leq
   -5 \\
 x-\frac{3}{2} \log (10-2 x)-5+10 \log
   (20) & -5<x\leq 0 \\
 \frac{13 x}{10}-5+10 \log (20)-\frac{3
   \log (10)}{2} & 0<x\leq 2 \\
 \frac{1}{10} \left(3
   x^2+x\right)-\frac{19}{5}+10 \log
   (20)-\frac{3 \log (10)}{2} & 2<x\leq
   5 \\
 \frac{3}{8} (4 x-10)+4 \log (4
   x-10)+\frac{9}{20}+10 \log
   (20)-\frac{11 \log (10)}{2} &
   \text{True}
\end{cases}$$
